# Flask Swagger UI not able to find swagger.json Fetch error Not Found /static/swagger.json Flask API Docker

Tags: python, docker, flask, swagger

I have built Flask API inside a Docker container and now I am trying to add Swagger UI to my application. Issue is, Even though the "swagger.json" is present in the directory and I am giving the right path, It still gives me the error. Checking the logs provides the following information:

```
"/home/faraz/python_docker/TestApp/app/static/swagger.json" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

I have double checked and can confirm that swagger.json exists and is present in the directory.

I am adding my code for views.py and where I have added Swagger specific code:

```
from app import app
from flask import render_template
from flask import request
from flask_swagger_ui import get_swaggerui_blueprint
#import pandas

@app.route('/')
def home():
   return "hello no  world!"

@app.route('/template',methods=['POST','GET'])
def template():
    output = request.args.values()
    return render_template('home.html',prediction_text="Listen to me... In this world, wherever there is light, there are always shadows. As long as there is a concept of victory, the vanquished will also exist. The selfish desire for peace give rise to war. And hatred is born in order to protect love. Wouldn't you agree {}?".format(list(output)[:]))
    

### swagger specific ###
SWAGGER_URL = '/swagger'
API_URL = '/static/swagger.json'
SWAGGERUI_BLUEPRINT = get_swaggerui_blueprint(
    SWAGGER_URL,
    API_URL,
    config={
        'app_name': "Seans-Python-Flask-REST-Boilerplate"
    }
)
app.register_blueprint(SWAGGERUI_BLUEPRINT, url_prefix=SWAGGER_URL)
### end swagger specific ###

@app.route("/static/swagger.json")
def specs():
    return send_from_directory(os.getcwd(), "swagger.json")

@app.route('/predict')
def predict():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

I am also Attaching my Dockerfile code and Start.sh code in case I have an issue in those files:

DockerFile:

```
FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.6-alpine3.7
RUN apk --update add bash nano
ENV STATIC_URL /static
ENV STATIC_PATH /home/faraz/python_docker/TestApp/app/static
COPY ./requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Start.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
app="docker.test_3"
docker build -t ${app} .
docker run -d -p 56734:80 \
  --name=${app} \
  -v $PWD:/app ${app}
```

I am also attaching the link to my Github Repository. Hopefully, Someone here can guide me in the right direction:
https://github.com/frazali32/Docker-flask-api-swagger

Answer (score 2):

Try to print the value of os.getcwd(). Maybe it doesn't return the value you are expecting.

I would advise you to use Path from pathlib for handling absolute and relative paths to files and directories:

```
from pathlib import Path

# Getting the absolute path for the current file (views.py)
BASE_PATH = Path(__file__).resolve().parent

(...)

return send_from_directory(BASE_PATH.joinpath('static'), 'swagger.json')
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. To test this theory, I commented out the following section:

@app.route("/static/swagger.json")
def specs():
    return send_from_directory(os.getcwd(), "swagger.json")

However, the error did not change and error log shows the same error as before. I believe views.py does not even get there before showing error. 

Is it possible that he path doesn't exist inside the container and I am mounting stuff in app? Please share your thoughts.

Comment: This answer solved my error of **Fetch error NOT FOUND** after spending a few hours trying to debug it. Although the printed value of `os.getcwd()` referred to the current directory, I guess there was some join problem in the paths.